# Body Composition Analyzer - How to calculate the fitness score?

Tags: bodybuilding, body-fat, body-measurements, measurements

How does the [InBody body composition analyzer](http://www.inbody.com/global/product/InBody720.aspx) calculate the fitness score?

Regarding the fitness score:

> The InBody Score is an arbitrary score based on the measured muscle and fat mass for the motivation of the subjects ([ref](http://inbody.com/_admin/uploads/GLOBAL/InBody720Nawi_CDmanual_Eng_A.pdf)).

Here is a sample result sheet from the maker's web site. See the bottom right corner for the fitness score:

[image: results sheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to ask them, as it's calculated using their own proprietary algorithm, well that or spend a few min's solving the simultaneous equation (from the values in your history) to work out the weights they've applied to your: Fat, Muscle, and Weight values to create the score:

> The fitness score is to help the subject to understand his/her body condition from a body composition point of view. The ideal is 100%. It is a piece of unique data provided by InBody720

and:

> ***Fitness Score**
>
> The Fitness Score is an index used to help the examinee easily understand the state of his/her body composition.
>
> 70 or less weak or obese type that need exercise and diet control
>
> 70~90 Normal, Healthy Type
>
> 90 or more Robust type with well-developed muscle

**FYI**: Using **R** to play with the DUMMY values above

```
weight <- c(65.7, 63.5, 61.2, 59.1)
smm <- c(20.6, 19.4, 19.4, 19.6)
fat <- c(27.0, 25.8, 23.5, 21.8)
score <- c(62, 63, 66, 68)
test.data = data.frame(score, weight, smm, fat)
lm(score ~ ., data = test.data)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Call:
lm(formula = score ~ ., data = test.data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       weight          smm          fat  
   75.67391      0.54987      0.01279     -1.85422
```

So for the DUMMY history above:

```
score = (0.54987 * weight) + (0.01279 * SMM) - (1.85422 * fat) + 75.67391
```

which if the same ratios hold in a real analysis, would suggest to exceed 100, you would need to have a **dangerously** low bodyFat %.

Comment: Wonderful analysis. I very much appreciate it! It looks in the ballpark. With my own numbers and the dummy formula above I would just exceed 103 points when on paper I'm at 97 points. It's interesting that SMM has negligible effect on the score though.

Comment: @Drakes - you can just alter the numbers and run the code eg. http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=lCB8ebYm